# Can't create connections to SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I just installed VS2012 Ultimate in my new machine (Windows 7 Ultimate), now I found out that I can't add new connections to SQL Server, it says that .\sqlexpress was not found.

It's as if the VS2012 installer didn't install the SQL Server Express a VS2010 does.

**What I'm I doing wrong?.**

[image http://s12.postimage.org/rez7k58e5/Sin_t_tulo.jpg](http://s12.postimage.org/rez7k58e5/Sin_t_tulo.jpg)

This is what's installed now:

[image2 http://s15.postimage.org/evugd03rv/Sin_t_tulo.jpg](http://s15.postimage.org/evugd03rv/Sin_t_tulo.jpg)

Comment: Install it separately, also you should know that sql server 2012's instance is not called sqlexpress. Should come up as `(LocalDb)\v11.0`

Comment: You need to specify that with your `ConnectionString` in `Web.config` file

Comment: Ok, I tried to open a project that contained access to a sql server express database, made with vs2010, and I got the message that sql server express is not installed in my machine, that the prefered database for vs2012 was local db express. No wonder why sqlexpress is not the sql instance. Does anybody know what's the sql instance name for a complete installation of VS2012? Clearly it's not ".\sqlexpress". I can install sql express, but if the preferred database is localdb express, it must be the VS2012 equivalent of sql express, it's ok for me...

Comment: It is now `(LocalDb)\v11.0`. User http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx to install your VS2012 softwares

Comment: Hi Komenge, Could you please write an answer so I can mark it as the right answer?